# PHP:How to add credit card method option in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card, mastercard

I have been working on paypal integration gateway in php. I have taken some tutorials from google. Now I want to add some credit card option via paypal like (visa, mastercard etc). Kindly guide me that how to add this functionality in php

**Here is simple html form**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="businesstest541@shop.com">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12oz Bottle">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
           src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
           alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
         src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>
```

Comment: that's all handled on PayPals side you don't do any type of that proccessing

Comment: But how to add visa card option in our side..

Answer (score 0):

To process cards on your own site, you'd need to use one of the Pro or Braintree options listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/).